# Foundation accordion-menu is not updating after dynamic add of node using knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, zurb-foundation

I am trying to simulate a tree view using `Foundation` framework and `Knockout`.

I have a Foundation accordion-menu which I am starting off with just a few nodes. As I click the accordion menu, I am querying the database and adding the child folders at this point.

I have based my tree view from the building block available at this link:

http://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/multilevel-accordion-menu.html

My HTML code looks like this

```
<ul id="treeview" data-bind='template: { name: "nodeTmpl", foreach: treeview }' class="multilevel-accordion-menu vertical menu" data-accordion-menu></ul>

<script id="nodeTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="click: $root.goToFolder">
        <a href="#" data-bind='text: node().DecryptedName'></a>
            <ul class="menu vertical sublevel-1" data-bind='attr: {id: "ul_" + node().ResourceId }, template: { name: "nodeTmpl", foreach: children }'></ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

My method `goToFolder` updates the object to add the nodes required.

My problem is that after this happens the accordian-menu doesn't refresh. It works like a charm if I run the following code, but this minimizes all the folders again which I don't want.

```
 $('#treeview').foundation('destroy');
 $('#treeview').foundation();
```

I have searched and searched but haven't found anything that works, including the following:

```
Foundation.reInit($('#treeview'));
Foundation.reInit('accordion-menu');
```

Can anyone suggest how I reinstate the accordion-menu without having to destroy each time?

Comment: You'll need to write a [custom binding handler](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) for the widget.

Comment: How are you updating your tree? In [my attempt to reproduce](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWpWvO), the accordion doesn't loose state at all when pushing to the initial array (in which case knockout will re-use elements and not redraw the whole thing). Are you creating a completely new tree?

Comment: Sorry it's an accordion-menu with sub items, like a tree view. It's more the sub items which aren't being updated properly. I am updating by pushing items into the array at the given node where I am clicking. The node goes in, but the accordion sub menu doesn't add the dropdown arrow.

Comment: It's worth mentioning I have based this accordion menu from the building block available here... http://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/multilevel-accordion-menu.html